# Dialog not filling screen

Tags: android, dialog

I have created a dialog for some data input and on some devices it is not filling the screen, it seems to be wrapping the content but on others it does fill the screen (as I would like).

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editSiteLocation_Layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editSiteLocation"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:hint="Site Location"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editWeatherConditions_Layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editWeatherConditions"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:hint="Weather Conditions"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddSite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    style="?attr/buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tested on two devices;

HTC One M9 (displayed how I want)

[image: This is what I want]

HTC One M9 (displayed how I want)

[image: This is not what I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can remember, You have to manipulate this programmatically like this:

```
   AlertDialog.Builder yourBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Dialog yourDialog = new Dialog(this);
     //do some stuff with your dialog and builder
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(yourDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    yourDialog = yourBuilder.create();
    yourDialog.show();
    yourDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll give this a go. Any ideas why it renders differently on such similar devices?

Comment: I think that´s how suppliers have made their own android build. Samsung with touchWiz, Huawei with EMUI etc...

Comment: So had a tinker and found that if I made the root element a `RelativeLayout` it also seemed to have the desired effect - in fact slightly better than the method you mentioned. I found that using the method you described the dialog was wider than I wanted (the gap from edge of screen to edge of dialog was about half what it is in the first picture).

Comment: You can do this also by setting exactly width and height. Using RelativeLayout could cause the same problem you had before on different devices.

Comment: But if I set absolute height and width values could it not look different on different screen sizes? I'm going for consistency, trying to match the width of the standard non-custom Android dialogs

Comment: Yes sure, but this is the same with all other screens. You should read about multiple screen support....http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html